# Bar plot with standard deviation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting bar plot with standard deviation in Matlab data are following

```
y = [0.776 0.707 1.269; 0.749 0.755 1.168; 0.813 0.734 1.270; 0.845 0.844 1.286];
std_dev = [0.01 0.055 0.052;0.067 0.119 0.106;0.036 0.077 0.060; 0.029 0.055 0.051];
```

I am writing following code

```
figure
hold on
bar(y)
errorbar(y,std_dev,'.')
```

But I am not getting standard deviation bar in the correct position.

Comment: This [post](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/318620-bar-matrix-with-errorbars-on-the-same-figure) may be helpful. But it may be appropriate to fill in a bug report/feature request for MATLAB.

Comment: Sorry I am getting standard deviation bar not in correct position

Comment: That is indeed the problem they solve in the link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

If all the bars have the same color:

```
x=1:15;
y = [0.776 0.707 1.269 0 0.749 0.755 1.168 0 0.813 0.734 1.270 0 0.845 0.844 1.286];
std_dev = [0.01 0.055 0.052 0 0.067 0.119 0.106 0 0.036 0.077 0.060 0 0.029 0.055 0.051];

figure
hold on
bar(x,y)
errorbar(y,std_dev ,'.')

XTickLabel={'1' ; '2'; '3' ; '4'};
XTick=2:4:15
set(gca, 'XTick',XTick);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', XTickLabel);
```

[image]